# Thai year 2558 to 2015

Tags: c#, datetime, date-format, cultureinfo

How to transform buddhist format of datetime into gregorian format (e.g. for Thailand 2558 → 2015)?

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThailandBuddhistCalendarTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        private const string DateTimeOffsetFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ci = new CultureInfo("th-TH");
            var today = DateTime.Now.ToString(DateFormat, ci); // today == "2558-05-22"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, in today is 2558-05-22

Comment: -543 years? ...

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.Now` generates your local time with `GregorianCalender` by default. If you wanna generate that time in your `ThaiBuddhistCalendar`, you can get it's values with an instance of that calender object.

Now you can use this values in [`DateTime(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32) constructor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to generate a `DateTime`.

After that, you can format your `DateTime` with a specific format.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
int thaiYear = new ThaiBuddhistCalendar().GetYear(now);
int thaiMonth = new ThaiBuddhistCalendar().GetMonth(now);
int thaiDay = new ThaiBuddhistCalendar().GetDayOfMonth(now);
int thaiHour = new ThaiBuddhistCalendar().GetHour(now);
int thaiMinute = new ThaiBuddhistCalendar().GetMinute(now);
int thaiSecond = new ThaiBuddhistCalendar().GetSecond(now);

var thaiDateTime = new DateTime(thaiYear, thaiMonth, thaiDay, thaiHour, thaiMinute, thaiSecond);
Console.WriteLine(thaiDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Result will be;

```
2558-05-22
```

From http://www.thaiworldview.com/feast/feast.htm

> There is a 543 years difference between the Buddhist calendar and the
>   Gregorian calendar. Year 2015 in Europe is year 2558 in Thailand.

If you looking for the opposite way, just use a culture that have Gregorian calender as a [`Calender`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.calendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) part like `InvariantCulture`.

```
var today = DateTime.Now.ToString(DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // 2015-05-22
```

Comment: `DateTime` is independent from any calendar. A call of `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", new CultureInfo("th-TH"))` results in '2558-05-22'.

Comment: @abto No. A `DateTime` is Gregorian Calender by default. Even [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) says; _The DateTime value type represents dates and times with values ranging from 00:00:00 (midnight), January 1, 0001 Anno Domini (Common Era) through 11:59:59 P.M., December 31, 9999 A.D. (C.E.) in the **Gregorian calendar**._ This `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", new CultureInfo("th-TH"))` generates `2558-05-22` because `th-TH` culture has `ThaiBuddhistCalendar` as a `DateTimeFormatInfo.Calender` property.

Comment: This only means it is valid in that range of the Gregorian Calendar. The date 2015-05-22 (Gregorian Calendar) is the same as 2558-05-22 (Thai Buddist Calendar), it only is another representation. You can verify this by comparing `gregorianCalendar.ToDateTime(2015,5,22,0,0,0,0)` to `buddhistCalendar.ToDateTime(2558,5,22,0,0,0,0)`.

Comment: @abto Exactly. I say _almost_ same things in a different way.

Comment: `buddhistCalendar.ToDateTime(2558,5,22,0,0,0,0) != new DateTime(2558,5,22,0,0,0,0)` but `buddhistCalendar.ToDateTime(2558,5,22,0,0,0,0) == new DateTime(2015,5,22,0,0,0,0)`.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to your question is, use a `Culture` which is using the `GregorianCalendar` as format provider, just like Soner Gönül suggest at the end of [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30393845/2029849).

However, **do not** try to adjust the `DateTime` so that its `Year` property would show `2558` instead of `2015`.

Even when the `DateTime` does not use a specific calendar for the stored date, it's properties always give the date and time parts based on the gregorian calendar. This leads to following:

```
buddhistCalendar.ToDateTime(2558,5,22,0,0,0,0) != new DateTime(2558,5,22,0,0,0,0)
```

but:

```
buddhistCalendar.ToDateTime(2558,5,22,0,0,0,0) == new DateTime(2015,5,22,0,0,0,0)
```

If you want to get the year, or any other value, of a given `DateTime` for a specific calendar, then use the appropriate method form that calendar like `calendar.GetYear(dateTime)`.

Otherwise you would get

```
new DateTime(2558,5,22,0,0,0,0).Year == 2558
```

but:

```
buddhistCalendar.GetYear(new DateTime(2558,5,22,0,0,0,0)) == 3101
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ThaiBuddhistCalendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.thaibuddhistcalendar(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

In example, if you know thai year, you can do this:

```
ThaiBuddhistCalendar cal = new ThaiBuddhistCalendar();
cal.ToDateTime(2558, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") // returns 2015-01-01
```

If you need get Thai `DateTime`, you can do this:

```
ThaiBuddhistCalendar cal = new ThaiBuddhistCalendar();
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime thai = new DateTime(cal.GetYear(now), cal.GetMonth(now), now.Day);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a simple way to solve your issue.

```
//First, Get your date in long type because we must use long in the next step.
//Or if you have your time in string type just use
//long yourDateTicks = Convert.ToDateTime(yourStringDate).Ticks;

long yourDateTicks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

//split your DateTime into Day, Month, Year.

int day = new DateTime(yourDateTicks).Day;
int month = new DateTime(yourDateTicks).Month;
int year = new DateTime(yourDateTicks).Year;

//Did you see the type of them above? Of course, It's Integer.
//So you can convert your year into B.C. by simply -543

int bcYear = year - 543;

//Finally, put your items into the blog again and format your desire.

DateTime bcDate = new DateTime(bcYear, month, day);
String bcDateFormat = bcDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Warning : If your local time is not in Thailand Your Year will be B.C - 543
[Let's Try it in the fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VnzJOS)